# Force a neural network to have 0-sum outputs

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I have a pytorch neural net with n-dimensional output which I want to have 0-sum during training (my training data, i.e. the true outputs, have 0 sum). Of course I could just add a line computing the sum s and then subtract s/n from each element of the output. But this way, the network would be driven even less to actually finding outputs with zero sum, as this would get taken care of anyways (I've been getting worse test results with this approach). Also, as the true outputs in the training data have 0 sum, obviously the network converges to having almost 0 sum outputs, but not quite. Hence, I was wondering whether there is a smart way to force the network to have outputs that sum to 0, without just brute-force subtracting the sum in the end (which would corrupt learning outputs to have sum 0)? I.e. some sort of solution directly incorporated in the network? (Probably there isn't, at least I couldn't think of any...)

Comment: Can you tell us anything else about your outputs? Are they bounded?

Comment: No they're not. They lie in R^n. But in practice they tend to not exceed a couple thousand.

Comment: I would look into the implementation of Softmax, which does almost exactly what you need, right? (Everything must add 1.) Perhaps you'll get your idea there.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach with "explicitly substracting the mean" is the correct way. The same way we use softmax to nicely parametrise distributions, and you could complain that "this makes the network not learn about probability even more!", but in fact it does, it simply does so in its own, unnormalised space. Same in your case - by subtracting the mean you make sure that you match the target variable while allowing your network to focus on hard problems, and not waste its compute on having to learn that the sum is zero. If you do anything else your network will literally have to learn to compute the mean somewhere and subtract it. There are some potential corner cases where there might be some deep representational reason for mean to be zero that could be argues for, but these cases are rare enough that chances that this is actually happening "magically" in the network are zero (and if you knew it was happening there would be better ways of targeting it than by zero ensuring).

Comment: Thanks for your response! I suppose you're right. I was kind of having the same feeling, but for some reason, in practice, this is giving me worse results than not subtracting the mean.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you add an explicit loss?

```py
pred = model(input)
original_loss = criterion(pred, target)
# add this loss
zero_sum_loss = pred.mean() ** 2
loss = original_loss + weight * zero_sum_loss
loss.backward()
optim.step()
# ...
```

Comment: I suppose you mean `zero_sum_loss=sum(pred)**2`? Well that would only tell the model to try to move towards zero sums again, which my original loss is already doing. I am really looking for a smart way to force the output to be 0 sum, just by construction of the network. I.e. some constraints on the weights or something? But I haven't been able to come up with anything useful. Maybe it's just not really possible haha

Comment: Or `pred.mean()`, yes that would also work. I might include something like this and see if it boosts performance. Thank you.

Comment: @joinijo usually `mean()` is preferred to `sum()` in loss functions to make it less sensitive to batch size. Though, I'm not sure this will do the trick in your case.